# Join 2 list of lists to list of tuples

Tags: python-2.7, tuples, list-comprehension

What is an efficient way of achieving the following?

***From:***

```
aList = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], ...]
bList = [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ...]
```

***To:***

```
Out = [('a', 1, 2, 3), ('b', 2, 3, 4), ('c', 3, 4, 5), ....]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list comprehension should do. The built-in function [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) returns one element from each list on each iteration step, then you concatenate both elements using the `+` operator, and finally you cast the resulting sublist to tuple by calling the built-in [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple).

*Demo:*

```
In [46]: aList = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]

In [47]: bList = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]

In [48]: Out = [tuple(b + a) for b, a in zip(bList, aList)]

In [49]: Out
Out[49]: [('a', 1, 2, 3), ('b', 2, 3, 4), ('c', 3, 4, 5)]
```